# How to divide the layer in Pixelmator?

Tags: pixelmator

Is it feasible to divide any layer in Pixelmator and then merge them again? I would like to convert this image (640 x 1136) to 640 x 960, but have to convert it without touching on the navigation and tab bar on the top and bottom of the screen. So I came up with an idea of first dividing the screen, and on one of the divided layer, cut 640 x 196 image, and then merge them again in order to archive 640 x 960 by only tinkering the white part.

However, it looks like it's impossible to divide the layer in Pixelmator - actually, the `slice` tool is only for the use of Web. So how can I get 640 x 960 image?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, it sounds like you may be familiar with vector based illustration tools but unfamiliar with raster based image editing tools.

In a vector based tool, you are working with objects. You can slice and cut and merge these objects to make new objects.

A raster based tool (typically) has just one object per layer, and that object is a whole bunch of pixels. The most typical tool for manipulating said pixels is using your selection tools (the 'marching ants').

So if you want to take one layer, and split parts out into separate layers, you select the portion you want to split out with your selection tool, cut it, then paste it into a new layer. Later, if you want to combine that back into one layer, use the MERGE LAYERS option in the layers pallet.

Comment: I don't even know what the vector based illustration tools are or what the raster based tools are... but based on your explanation, Pixelmator is raster-based tools, right? And then is it feasible to select the portion of the layer with the fixed size such as 640 x 196 being preset? I mean, I see it too hard and daunting a task to try to select 640 x 196 with moving a cursor in trackpad - so want to first select the size (640 x 196) and then fit it into my portion of the layer that I want to select...

Comment: OK, the answer from Ausra in [this page](http://support.pixelmator.com/viewtopic.php?t=7292) clarifies how to select it by size and I solved my task properly. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, pixelmator has pretty good tutorials and discussion boards on their website. I'd suggest spending some time reading through those to get a feel for the software.